# How do I install PHP5.4.16 on Debian Wheezy?

Tags: php, debian

I used to be able to install `php-5fpm=5.4.16-1~dotdeb.1`, but it seems that this package is no longer available from the latest dotdeb packages.

Here are the steps I tried.

1. Append the following two lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

   `deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all`

   `deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all`
2. Run `apt-get update`.
3. Run `apt-get install php5-fpm=5.4.16-1~dotdeb.1`.

However, this returns `E: Version '5.4.16-1~dotdeb.1' for 'php5-fpm' was not found`. I tried to avoid it by using a different respository, namely, `deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php54 all`, but this returned the same message. How can I install that specific version of PHP?